# php returns error after successfully dropping my table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am successfully getting data from a mysql data base until I try to drop a table.   The table drops, but I cannot figure out how to keep the javascript ajax data base access from declaring an error.

How can I return ok, when there is no data to return?

The following php routine deletes a row in the order table followed by dropping the table named $tableNameInput.    Inspection of the database reveals that both operations were successfully performed but the javascript ajax error processing is tripped with x.status = 0.  I just need a way to tell the javascript ajax that it is really complete.

```
function dropCartTable($tableNameInput){/* drops the cart table and its order entry*/
    AnnLog("dropCartTable: ",$tableNameInput);
    // first drop the reference in the orders table
    $tableName = "orders";
    $query = "DELETE FROM $tableName WHERE cartDB ='$tableNameInput'";
    $result = doQuery($tableName,$query, "Could not drop orders row");
    if($result){
        // now drop this cart table
        $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tableNameInput";
    }
    //********do query  just does the query and logs.   it does not return if it dies.
    $result = doQuery($tableName, $sql, "Can not drop csrt table");
    if($result){

        /****** when we get to here we have successfully dropped the items. below, I tried to generate a response and it did not work.*/

        $arr = array('drop cart' => 0);
        $j = json_encode ($arr);
        echo \json_encode($j);
        AnnLog("echoed ",$j);/* this writes my logs which verify that all steps until the return are ok.*/

    }
}
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are double-encoding your JSON why not just `echo json_encode($arr);`?

Answer (score 1):

```
function dropCartTable($tableNameInput){/* drops the cart table and its order entry*/
AnnLog("dropCartTable: ",$tableNameInput);
// first drop the reference in the orders table
$tableName = "orders";
$query = "DELETE FROM $tableName WHERE cartDB ='$tableNameInput'";
$result = doQuery($tableName,$query, "Could not drop orders row");
if($result)
{
         // now drop this cart table
        $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $tableNameInput";
$arr = array('drop cart' => 0);
     $j = json_encode ($arr);
    echo \json_encode($j);
AnnLog("echoed ",$j);/* this writes my logs which verify that all steps until the return are ok.*/

}
else
{
$arr = array("couldn't drop cart" => 0);
         $j = json_encode ($arr);
        echo \json_encode($j);
    AnnLog("echoed ",$j);/* .*/
}
```

> The problem was that you was dropping the table and return result if
>   its true and ignoring false

Comment: Somehow some lines were deleted from above.  There are actually two queries, one to the order table and the other to the cart table.   In both cases I call a function called doquery which handles the query and logs to my log files.   If the query fails, the log file is updated and the process dies.   The if ($result is rednundant. My problem is that the json_encode does not make it back to the calling rountine.   I get error number 0.  Bad formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the json return.    It was caused by my failure to have a success callback for the ajax call.

Comment: How do we get this closed?